# Pentaho Report Designer for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I just downloaded Pentaho Business Analytics to try its reporting features on a Windows 8 machine. Currently I'm trying to use Report Designer to create a report for a MongoDB datasource, so following the guidelines from the book, I'm using these steps:

1. Select the Data Tab.
2. Right Click on the Data Sets item.
3. Select MongoDB from the menu.
4. Click on the plus button to create a query

And that is the point where things differ from the book, because I get this form:

[image: New Data Source form]

According to the book, I should be able to enter a host name, port, and have the option to select a collection, but the form I get doesn't allow me that. Does anyone face this issue, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The options are hidden; stretch the window!